# Lambda security group to S3 and Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-secrets-manager

I'm new to Terraform (TF) and AWS. I've created TF that creates an RDS cluster, VPC and security groups, S3 bucket, secrets in secrets manager (SM), as well as a lambda that access all of the above. I've attached the RDS VPC and security group to the lambda. So the code in the lambda can successfully access the RDS. My problem is that I need a security group that allow the lambda code to read from secrets manager to get RDS user accounts and S3 to get sql scripts to execute on the RDS. So, a security group with outbound to S3 and secrets manager.

How do i get terraform to calculate (data) the details to the SM and S3. Then use this info to create the security group to allow the lambda code to access SM and S3.

Currently I'm forcing my way with "All to All on 0.0....", this will not be allowed in the production environment.

Comment: Have you tried using a Secrets Manager with VPC Endpoints? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoint-overview.html This will allow access from your "Lambda in VPC" to SSM. You can also use an S3 VPC Endpoint for that matter. Bare in mind that it's not free, and has extra costs, especially for intensive usage. For your scenario, it sounds ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, a security group with outbound to S3 and secrets manager.

The easiest way would be to use **S3 VPC interface endpoint**, not S3 gateway. Thus if you have two endpoints for S3 and SM, both will be associated with SG that you must have created in your code, or they will use default one.

So to simply limit access of your lambda to the S3 and SM, you have just **reference** the interface's SGs in your lambda's SG.

Comment: How do I set this up in terraform